# Python: Determine a time interval within the time interval

Tags: python

I have a file with the following data:

```
local_time           asset
2022-10-04 07:14:31  12345
2022-10-04 07:14:22  12345
2022-10-01 18:43:19  67899
```

I need to calculate the following information:

1. Determine the time interval in minutes between local_time per asset.
2. In the second column, I want to see if there were times between 9 pm and 6 am in the time interval 1) and display that in minutes.
3. Difference from 1) and 2)

Thanks a lot!

for 1) I already used the following code

```py
df['duration_min'] = round((df.groupby('assetline')['local_time'].shift(-1).sub(df['local_time']).dt.total_seconds()/60).abs(),1)
```

But I have difficulties with 2)

Comment: hi Sofia! Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: quick question: are we assuming that there will always be 2 times per asset? or can we assume that it will be at most 2? Or something else?

Comment: Hi Mark, there will be more then 2 times per asset